# How to use PHP path inside JWplayer Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jwplayer, path-variables

How do I write my php path with variables inside the embedded JWplayer Javascript?
I am new to php and have no code experience in Javascript.
I would appreciate any help.

```
**This absolute path works:**
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "/uploads/example.mp4",
    height: 360,
    image:  "http://saradyso.com:8020/SuperContainer/RawData/MediaWeb/REG002133749/ADP100000033/Video1.mp4",
    width: 640
    });
 </script>

**This doesn't work:**
<script type="text/javascript">
 jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "/uploads/example.mp4",
    height: 360,
    image:"http://'.$Domain.':'.$Port.'/'.$ContainerV.'/'.$FileName.'/'.$SubFolder.'.mp4'",
    width: 640
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want a php script that returns an mp4 file ?

Answer (score 2):

Just like that

```
<?php $your_path = "some/path/to/to.image" ?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "/uploads/example.mp4",
    height: 360,
    image: <?php ehco $your_path ?>,
    width: 640
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use echo inside php block like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "/uploads/example.mp4",
    height: 360,
    image:"http://<?php echo $Domain ?>:<?php echo $Port ?>/<?php echo $ContainerV ?>/<?php echo $SubFolder ?>/<?php echo $FileName ?>.mp4",
    width: 640
    });
 </script>
```